# System Monitor display squares instead of characters

Tags: 18.04, gnome, system-monitor

When I open my system monitor it looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed it and reinstalled it via the Software Center and that fixed it.